# WPF Combobox Autocomplete TextSearch like "Contains" instead of "Start with"

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, autocomplete, text-search

I am trying to implement WPF Combobox Autocomplete TextSearch like "Contains" instead of "Start with".

Couple of question threads are there but could not find any concrete solution.

I was following the answer by @Evgenii:
[WPF combobox textsearch with contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427341/wpf-combobox-textsearch-with-contains)

In the SetText(DependencyObject element, string text) method, the value of "text" parameter is always a "DeviceNumber" string. So my text is not reflecting there.

Here is my own sample code 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eqK5bh5SQJPxHeb-zzOuBHIpYapv-h18

Any reason?

Is anyone successfully implemented Text Search with Contains?
Please guide.

I thank you for every answer I get but working code is much appreciable :)

Comment: Thanks @NawedNabiZada. I tried that before writing this post. It was not working.
I just tried again but no luck.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and I doubt anybody will put the effort to click on a link to google drive to download your solution. I will advice you to retry the code provided in the link above, and ask questions regarding the issues you would face. Make sure to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No hard feelings. Stackoverflow is not a forum for discussion, as the guide lines describe your current question is too broad. You  still need to create a MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make custom combobox control.

```
public class SearchComboBox : ComboBox
{
    TextBox editableTextBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        editableTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;

        editableTextBox.TextChanged += EditableTextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    private void EditableTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView ICV = ItemsSource as ICollectionView;

        if(ICV != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(editableTextBox.Text.Trim()))
                ICV.Filter = null;
            else
                ICV.Filter = new Predicate<object>(i => ((Equipment)i).equipmentLabel.Contains(editableTextBox.Text));

            IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }

    }
}
```

modify you EquipmentScreenViewModel Code. add ICollectionView type property

```
public  class EquipmentScreenViewModel
{
    public string SelectedEquipmentRego { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Equipment> AllEquipments { get; set; }

    private ICollectionView _allEquipCollection = null;

    public ICollectionView AllEquipCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_allEquipCollection == null && AllEquipments != null)
            {
                _allEquipCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllEquipments);
            }

            return _allEquipCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <local:SearchComboBox x:Name="cmbAlternativeAsset" 
                            Width="200" IsEditable="True" 
                            FontSize="12" Foreground="#494949"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEquipmentRego, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding AllEquipCollection}" SelectedValuePath="equipmentRego"
                            DisplayMemberPath="equipmentLabel" IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
        />
</Grid>
```

Binding ItemsSource to CollectionView and IsTextSearchEnabled false. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

i recommend using  `AutoCompleteBox`, it 's just like `ComboBox`, it has `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` and all like `ComboBox`

you can use it property 'AutoCompleteBox.FilterMode' which take `AutoCompleteFilterMode` enumeration, the enumerations include:`Contains`, `ContainsCaseSensitive`, `ContainsOrdinal`
and other helpful ... 
here is how you use it:

https://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-autocompletebox-autocomplete-text.html
and here it an example of using filter mode:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/dd833103(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I believe the easiest way to get this now is via the updated github/nuget -> https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit